# Filtering Solr search results based on score

Tags: solr, content-search

I'm trying to figure out a way to apply a filter on result scores. E.g. I want only results with score >50.

In pure Solr, that is solved by using a filter query. Adding the following to the query string has the desired effect:

```
fq={!frange l=50}query($q,0)
```

I've tried with standard LinqToSolr, e.g. `.Where(x => x.Score>50)`, but that of course doesn't work because field `score` is not defined at search time.

Is there a way to apply this logic through ContentSearch and LinqToSolr? Or extend a pipeline to add the filter query to all requests sent to Solr?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using `.Filter` instead of `.Where` to add the query to your filter query?

Comment: Yes, I did. Same result, solr returns error "field score not defined" (or something similar)

Comment: I think you will need to do post filtration based on the score, e.g. `results.Hits.Where(hit => hit.Score > 0.5)` because for sure score is calculated after query is executed, and any additional query might affect the score. But if you have low score and just a few results - that doesn't mean results are not relevant, that is why usually 'Top N' results are used, not top F score.

Comment: @Daniil, the problem with post filtering is 1) the need to retrieve too many results from solr; 2) impossible to let solr do sorting (it if different from score-based) and paging. 
The solr does allow restricting score by means of filter query (fq), it is just Sitecore doesn't support that apparently. Shame on you, Sitecore :D

Comment: Your only option is to extend Sitecore with that logic unfortunately